# SSD dead and stopped working

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I was copying media file from my **Skhynix SC308 SATA 256GB** which I used as a storage drive,
The drive was connected via external USB enclosure. It eventually went off when I was copying a media file from the drive to my PC running Debian 10.
I have taken the below steps to see if it would work.

I tried another USB port, it didn't come up, 
I plugged it into a Windows OS, it didn't come up, 
I used it as my laptop primary drive, it wasn't detected in the BIOS, 
I replaced the SSD with a spare HDD, HDD worked fine, this shows that problem is neither from external USB enclosure nor the OS but the SSD.

Does anyone have clue on how to get it working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like hooey but I've seen the same solution from several sources.  Power up the drive (without data cable unless it's a NVMe or M.2 SSD).  for 30 minutes.  Power down or disconnect for 30 seconds.  Repeat.  Now try the drive normally.  If this doesn't work there should be a three to five year warranty on a SSD.  Good luck!

Comment: I have tried related solutions but it never worked for me.